# Fetching XML tag data stored in a varchar2 column

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table as below:

```
    ID  Name      Roll         Data
    1   ABC        12       <ngc_mid_nu_3><tid_nu><status>A</status> 
                            <term_no>03</term_no> 
                            </tid_nu><tid_nu><status>A</status> 
                            <term_no>04</term_no> 
                            </tid_nu><ngc_mid_nu_3>
   2    XYZ        32       <ngc_mid_nu_3><tid_nu><status>B</status> 
                            <term_no>08</term_no> 
                            </tid_nu><tid_nu><status>A</status> 
                            <term_no>04</term_no> 
                            </tid_nu><ngc_mid_nu_3>
```

All the columns are `varchar2` including the column named Data.

I want to fetch the values present inside `<status>` tag and `<term_no>` tag for each row. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cross-join your table rows with an XMLTable that extracts all of the fields you want:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.roll, x.status, x.term_no
from your_table t
cross join xmltable ('/ngc_mid_nu_3/tid_nu'
  passing xmltype(t.data)
  columns status varchar2(10) path 'status',
    term_no varchar2(10) path 'term_no'
) x;
```

Set the `columns` data types and sizes appropriately for the data you expect to really see.

Demo with your sample data in a CTE (with fixed closing tags in your XML - i.e. `</ngc_mid_nu_3>` instead of `<ngc_mid_nu_3>`):

```
with your_table (ID, Name, Roll, Data) as (
select 1, 'ABC', 12, '<ngc_mid_nu_3><tid_nu><status>A</status> 
<term_no>03</term_no> 
</tid_nu><tid_nu><status>A</status> 
<term_no>04</term_no> 
</tid_nu></ngc_mid_nu_3>' from dual
union all
select 2, 'XYZ', 32, '<ngc_mid_nu_3><tid_nu><status>B</status> 
<term_no>08</term_no> 
</tid_nu><tid_nu><status>A</status> 
<term_no>04</term_no> 
</tid_nu></ngc_mid_nu_3>' from dual
)
select t.id, t.name, t.roll, x.status, x.term_no
from your_table t
cross join xmltable ('/ngc_mid_nu_3/tid_nu'
  passing xmltype(t.data)
  columns status varchar2(10) path 'status',
    term_no varchar2(10) path 'term_no'
) x;

        ID NAME             ROLL STATUS     TERM_NO   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 ABC                12 A          03        
         1 ABC                12 A          04        
         2 XYZ                32 B          08        
         2 XYZ                32 A          04
```

If your real XML strings are actually malformed - missing the slash in the final closing tag - then you need to fix that first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am getting the below error:                                
 ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

Comment: @AnitaPrasad - the example in your question doesn't have proper closing tags; as I said I corrected those. They should end with `</ngc_mid_nu_3>', with a slash. I assumed you'd just omitted those retyping the data for the question. Is your real data like that, with malformed XML?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes I missed it. But the real data is not malformed. It does have proper closing tags.

Comment: @AnitaPrasad - well, the error you got suggests you have at least one row where the data is malformed...

Comment: Hey, yes there is a data which is malformed in the existing table. Eliminating that row the query is working perfectly. Thank you so much for help.